# Cannot Map Drive with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, drive

Not sure why this does not work as the path is correct.  Am i better not using a process and using some other method?, and do i need to do anything to make it persistent.?

Apologies if this is already out there.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:/windows/system32/net.exe", " use R: \\data01\SHARED\Admin\111\Town\0 National Sales & Towns\02. Project Office\04. MSS Tracker Database\App")
    MessageBox.Show("All done !")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in your path:

```
\\[..snip..]n\0 National Sales & Towns\02. Proje[..snip..]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---path to map, leading to unknown file "0"
                  ^-------^-- unknown args for net use
                               ^--shell command separator
                                    ^^^^---unknown command/path, etc...
```

The path needs to be entirely quoted:

```
"\\[..snip..]n\0 National Sales & Towns\02. Proje[..snip..]"
^----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:/windows/system32/net.exe", " use R: " & "\\data01\SHARED\Admin\111\Town\0 National Sales & Towns\02. Project Office\04. MSS Tracker Database\App")

Comment: Do i have to put the quotes round the specific sections that have spaces then or the full string?

Comment: no. that does NOTHING. you're generating the exact same string, just now it's 2 vb strings, not one. the quotes have to be in the command line itself. `net use r: "....", exactly as if you'd typed it on the cmd.exe prompt yourself.

Comment: `& """\\data01\SHARED\Admin\111\Town\0 National Sales & Towns\02 ...  Database\App"""` enter two " to insert into a string.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:/windows/system32/net.ext", "use r: " & """\\data01\SHARED\Admin\111\Town\0 National Sales & Towns\02. Project Office\04. MSS Tracker Database\App""")